# passing a generic view template as a function argument

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I've got a few controller functions that use different view templates for rendering. These work as expected, however, the code in the controller functions are very similar and beg to be refactored into a common function. So, I need something like so:

```
def controller1() = Action {
  // call some controller1-specific logic here
  refactoredFunc(views.html.view1)
}

def controller2() = Action {
  // call some controller2-specific logic here
  refactoredFunc(views.html.view2)
}

def refactoredFunc(view: play.api.templates.Html) = {
  // some common logic here
  Ok(view)
}
```

The above works (well, at least it compiles), but I am unhappy about specifying that `refactoredFunc` only accepts `Html` templates as input as that is an artificial constraint that need not be there.

I've tried replacing `play.api.templates.Html` with `play.api.templates.BufferedContent[_]` but the compiler does not like that.

So, is there a generic way I can do this without mandating that the view be Html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to introduce a type parameter in your refactoredFunc. Due to the mecanism used by Play to send the response, you also need to declare an implicit `Writeable` parameter.

```
def refactoredFunc[C](view: C)(implicit writeable: Writeable[C]) = {
    Ok(view)
}
```

With this code, you can call `refactoredFunc` with any type `C` which have a `Writeable[C]` implicitly available. Play will automatically define these implicits for its common use cases, like `Html`,....

Comment: Thanks! While that wasn't the exact solution I needed (I had overly simplified my problem description - the views take arguments too) - it did point me in the right direction: